# How can I make my javascript button to post a certain message?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chat room,instead of chatting I need my "send message" button to send the user,username he wrote in the register form, into the chat.Nothing else but the username.

```
function make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name)
{
    var modal_content = '<div id="user_dialog_'+to_user_id+'" class="user_dialog" title="You have chat with '+to_user_name+'">';
    modal_content += '<div style="height:400px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:24px; padding:16px;" class="chat_history" data-touserid="'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_history_'+to_user_id+'">';
    modal_content += fetch_user_chat_history(to_user_id);
    modal_content += '</div>';
    modal_content += '<div class="form-group">';
    modal_content += '<textarea name="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" class="form-control chat_message"></textarea>';
    modal_content += '</div><div class="form-group" align="right">';
    modal_content+= '<button type="button" name="send_chat" id="'+to_user_id+'" class="btn btn-info send_chat">Send</button></div></div>';
    $('#user_model_details').html(modal_content);
}

$(document).on('click', '.start_chat', function(){
    var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid');
    var to_user_name = $(this).data('tousername');
    make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name);
    $("#user_dialog_"+to_user_id).dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        width:400
    });
    $('#user_dialog_'+to_user_id).dialog('open');
    $('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).emojioneArea({
        pickerPosition:"top",
        toneStyle: "bullet"
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.send_chat', function(){
    var to_user_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var chat_message = $.trim($('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).val());
    if(chat_message != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert_chat.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{to_user_id:to_user_id, chat_message:chat_message},
            success:function(data)
            {
                //$('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).val('');
                var element = $('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).emojioneArea();
                element[0].emojioneArea.setText('');
                $('#chat_history_'+to_user_id).html(data);
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Type something');
    }
});
```

this is the entire **index.php**

```
<?php include('database_connection.php'); session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { header("location:login.php"); } ?> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> <title>Chat Application using PHP Ajax Jquery</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css"> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js"></script> </head> <body> <div class="container"> <br /> <h3 align="center">Chat Application using PHP Ajax Jquery</h3><br /> <br /> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6"> <h4>Online User</h4> </div> <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3"> <input type="hidden" id="is_active_group_chat_window" value="no" /> <button type="button" name="group_chat" id="group_chat" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Group Chat</button> </div> <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3"> <p align="right">Hi - <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> - <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> </div> </div> <div class="table-responsive"> <div id="user_details"></div> <div id="user_model_details"></div> </div> <br /> <br /> </div> </body> </html> <style> .chat_message_area { position: relative; width: 100%; height: auto; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 3px; } #group_chat_message { width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 80px; overflow: auto; padding:6px 24px 6px 12px; } .image_upload { position: absolute; top:3px; right:3px; } .image_upload > form > input { display: none; } .image_upload img { width: 24px; cursor: pointer; } </style> <div id="group_chat_dialog" title="Group Chat Window"> <div id="group_chat_history" style="height:400px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:24px; padding:16px;"> </div> <div class="form-group"> <!--<textarea name="group_chat_message" id="group_chat_message" class="form-control"></textarea>!--> <div class="chat_message_area"> <div id="group_chat_message" contenteditable class="form-control"> </div> <div class="image_upload"> <form id="uploadImage" method="post" action="upload.php"> <label for="uploadFile"><img src="upload.png" /></label> <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" accept=".jpg, .png" /> </form> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group" align="right"> <button type="button" name="send_group_chat" id="send_group_chat" class="btn btn-info">Send</button> </div> </div> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ fetch_user(); setInterval(function(){ update_last_activity(); fetch_user(); update_chat_history_data(); fetch_group_chat_history(); }, 5000); function fetch_user() { $.ajax({ url:"fetch_user.php", method:"POST", success:function(data){ $('#user_details').html(data); } }) } function update_last_activity() { $.ajax({ url:"update_last_activity.php", success:function() { } }) } function make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name) { var modal_content = '<div id="user_dialog_'+to_user_id+'" class="user_dialog" title="You have chat with '+to_user_name+'">'; modal_content += '<div style="height:400px; border:1px solid #ccc; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom:24px; padding:16px;" class="chat_history" data-touserid="'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_history_'+to_user_id+'">'; modal_content += fetch_user_chat_history(to_user_id); modal_content += '</div>'; modal_content += '<div class="form-group">'; modal_content += '<textarea name="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" id="chat_message_'+to_user_id+'" class="form-control chat_message"></textarea>'; modal_content += '</div><div class="form-group" align="right">'; modal_content+= '<button type="button" name="send_chat" id="'+to_user_id+'" class="btn btn-info send_chat">Send</button></div></div>'; $('#user_model_details').html(modal_content); } $(document).on('click', '.start_chat', function(){ var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid'); var to_user_name = $(this).data('tousername'); make_chat_dialog_box(to_user_id, to_user_name); $("#user_dialog_"+to_user_id).dialog({ autoOpen:false, width:400 }); $('#user_dialog_'+to_user_id).dialog('open'); $('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).emojioneArea({ pickerPosition:"top", toneStyle: "bullet" }); }); $(document).on('click', '.send_chat', function(){ var to_user_id = $(this).attr('id'); var chat_message = $.trim($('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).val()); if(chat_message != '') { $.ajax({ url:"insert_chat.php", method:"POST", data:{to_user_id:to_user_id, chat_message:chat_message}, success:function(data) { //$('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).val(''); var element = $('#chat_message_'+to_user_id).emojioneArea(); element[0].emojioneArea.setText(''); $('#chat_history_'+to_user_id).html(data); } }) } else { alert('Type something'); } }); function fetch_user_chat_history(to_user_id) { $.ajax({ url:"fetch_user_chat_history.php", method:"POST", data:{to_user_id:to_user_id}, success:function(data){ $('#chat_history_'+to_user_id).html(data); } }) } function update_chat_history_data() { $('.chat_history').each(function(){ var to_user_id = $(this).data('touserid'); fetch_user_chat_history(to_user_id); }); } $(document).on('click', '.ui-button-icon', function(){ $('.user_dialog').dialog('destroy').remove(); $('#is_active_group_chat_window').val('no'); }); $(document).on('focus', '.chat_message', function(){ var is_type = 'yes'; $.ajax({ url:"update_is_type_status.php", method:"POST", data:{is_type:is_type}, success:function() { } }) }); $(document).on('blur', '.chat_message', function(){ var is_type = 'no'; $.ajax({ url:"update_is_type_status.php", method:"POST", data:{is_type:is_type}, success:function() { } }) }); $('#group_chat_dialog').dialog({ autoOpen:false, width:400 }); $('#group_chat').click(function(){ $('#group_chat_dialog').dialog('open'); $('#is_active_group_chat_window').val('yes'); fetch_group_chat_history(); }); $('#send_group_chat').click(function(){ var chat_message = $.trim($('#group_chat_message').html()); var action = 'insert_data'; if(chat_message != '') { $.ajax({ url:"group_chat.php", method:"POST", data:{chat_message:chat_message, action:action}, success:function(data){ $('#group_chat_message').html(''); $('#group_chat_history').html(data); } }) } else { alert('Type something'); } }); function fetch_group_chat_history() { var group_chat_dialog_active = $('#is_active_group_chat_window').val(); var action = "fetch_data"; if(group_chat_dialog_active == 'yes') { $.ajax({ url:"group_chat.php", method:"POST", data:{action:action}, success:function(data) { $('#group_chat_history').html(data); } }) } } $('#uploadFile').on('change', function(){ $('#uploadImage').ajaxSubmit({ target: "#group_chat_message", resetForm: true }); }); $(document).on('click', '.remove_chat', function(){ var chat_message_id = $(this).attr('id'); if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this chat?")) { $.ajax({ url:"remove_chat.php", method:"POST", data:{chat_message_id:chat_message_id}, success:function(data) { update_chat_history_data(); } }) } }); }); </script>
```

I have all these files:

database_connection

db

fetch_user

fetch_user_chat_history

group_chat

index

insert_chat

login

logout

register

remove_chat

update_is_typ e_status

update_last_activity

upload

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML as well

Comment: hello,I did now

Comment: It is a little hard to understand exactly what you want from the question. A concise example of the issue and desired outcome along with any error messages from the code you have tried would help a lot. Please have a read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I edited the question,is it better?

Answer (score 1):

Instead to use a button use

```
    <input type="button" onclick="seperator('"+ [ PHP or JS STUFF ]+ "');">";
```

and maybee you define also a hidden input element

```
     <input type=hidden id="user", name = "user">
```

Instead of sending the form he will now call a javascript function first.
in this function you can now do whatever you need and also finally submit the form if needed. I create a prototype for you ( to be included or build in the js as usual)
you may modify it acc. your needs for sure. Just to give you a idea :)

```
   <script>
       function seperator(phpin){
        // check if value is there
       if (typeof phpin ==="undefined"){
            alert("PHP ERROR: Please fill the whole form !");
           return;
       }
       // get the form by form id

        //split the value by " " 
        var h=phpin.split();
        //separate value parts
        var username=h[0];
        var whatever=h[1];
        // get the hidden field
         var hidden =documentGetElemetById("user");
         //fill the hidden field
          hidden.value=username;
          //here you can call now also your submit function instead of this 
          //here or comment it out
         //get the form   
          var form=documentGetElemetById("formid");
         //submit form
          form.submit();
        }
      </script>
```

have fun.

Comment: I can't have fun if I don't get what I want :c thx for your answer but I don't have any clue how would help me separating the username with any other words/sentences/messages etc.maybe I miss something

Comment: I thought is a simple task thats why I asked :) don't waste your time if it's a hard problem

Comment: @AlexPop if you have a new problem then ask a new question. Don't keep adding new things into an existing one. Separating the words was not what you originally asked about. Thanks

Comment: @AlexPop you specifically asked "how would help me separating the username with any other words", which sounds like a different problem to me. Do you need help with that, or not? Are you saying that there is something wrong with the answer? If so please describe the problem rather than phrasing it like a new question. Then we can all be clear what you really mean

Comment: Alex you are really a pleasure to meet here :) You are welcome :)